# HashMap deleting itself inside a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

The goal of my project is to create a League of teams, and have rosters of each teams. I'm supposed to use 2 different maps. One map is for holding the Team name as a string, with it's object (Team). The other map is for holding the roster with the number and the object (Player). Whenever I run this code, and try to test whether the roster is printing out the right numbers, I have a problem. The roster seems to clear itself whole. I know that I have put a Roster.clear() method in, but that is to reset the roster to put players from other teams in. If you need the team class, I will put it in at the bottom. Thank you SO much if anyone is able to answer my question.

```
import java.util.*;

public class League{

    public League(Scanner s){
        Map<String,Team> League = new HashMap<String,Team>();
        Map<Integer,Player> Roster = new HashMap<Integer, Player>();
        Team t;
        Player p;
        String team,
        name;
        Boolean throwsRightHanded;

        int number,
        position,
        plateApp,
        walks,
        strikeouts,
        hits,
        inningsPitched,
        earnedRuns,
        atBats,
        runsBattedIn,
        homeRuns,
        hitByPitch;
        team = s.next();


        while (s.hasNext()){
            if (!s.hasNext("-1")){
                number = s.nextInt();
                name = s.next();
                position = s.nextInt();
                if (s.next() == "t"){
                    throwsRightHanded = true;
                }
                else{
                    throwsRightHanded = false;
                }
                plateApp = s.nextInt();
                walks = s.nextInt();
                strikeouts = s.nextInt();
                hits = s.nextInt();
                if (position == 1){
                    //Pitcher
                    inningsPitched = s.nextInt();
                    earnedRuns = s.nextInt();
                    p = new Pitcher(inningsPitched, earnedRuns, number, name, position, 
                            throwsRightHanded, plateApp, walks, strikeouts, hits);
                }
                else{
                    atBats = s.nextInt();
                    runsBattedIn = s.nextInt();
                    homeRuns = s.nextInt();
                    hitByPitch = s.nextInt();
                    p = new PositionPlayer(atBats, runsBattedIn, homeRuns, hitByPitch, number, name, position, 
                            throwsRightHanded, plateApp, walks, strikeouts, hits);
                }

                Roster.put(number, p);
            }
            else{
                t = new Team(team, Roster);
                League.put(team, t);
                Roster.clear();
                s.next();
                if (s.hasNext())
                    team = s.next();
            }
        }
        Iterator<Team> it = League.values().iterator();
        Team teamIterator;
        while (it.hasNext()){
            teamIterator = it.next();
            System.out.println(teamIterator);
            Iterator<Player> itt = teamIterator.getRoster().values().iterator();
            while (itt.hasNext()){
                System.out.println(itt.next());
            }
        }
    }
```

The important part is below:

```
            else{
                t = new Team(team, Roster);
                League.put(team, t);
                Roster.clear();
                s.next();
                if (s.hasNext())
                    team = s.next();
            }
        }
        Iterator<Team> it = League.values().iterator();
        Team teamIterator;
        while (it.hasNext()){
            teamIterator = it.next();
            System.out.println(teamIterator);
            Iterator<Player> itt = teamIterator.getRoster().values().iterator();
            while (itt.hasNext()){
                System.out.println(itt.next());
            }
        }
    }
```

Team Class:

```
public class Team{
    private Map<Integer,Player> roster;
    private String t;

    public Team(String tname, Map<Integer,Player> floatroster){
        setRoster(floatroster);
        t = tname;
    }

    public String lookupPlayer(int n){
        if (!roster.containsKey(n)){
            System.out.println("No player with number " + n + " is on the roster for the " + t);
            return null;
        }
        else{
            return roster.values().toString();
        }
    }
    public String toString(){
        return t;
    }
    public void setRoster(Map<Integer,Player> floatroster){
        roster = floatroster;
    }
    public Map<Integer, Player> getRoster(){
        return roster;
    }

}
```

File I'm reading from:

```
RedSox
65 Jonathan 1 t 416 23 80 111
259 32 
68 Matt 1 t 399 28 56 90
241 37 
32 Craig 1 f 383 29 55 121
245 35 
11 Clay 1 t 418 32 63 105
241 37 
46 Ryan 1 t 408 24 59 97
228 35 
51 Edwin 1 f 392 32 64 82
232 36 
37 Heath 1 t 419 31 53 109
233 38 
62 Rich 1 f 411 33 36 77
263 36 
61 Brian 1 f 397 25 59 107
240 32 
56 Joe 1 t 390 32 57 89
201 36 
59 Tommy 1 f 408 26 69 104
284 35 
64 Jean 1 t 421 44 37 94
263 33 
70 Roman 1 t 428 31 46 91
252 35 
20 Wade 1 f 386 36 49 73
256 38 
41 Alex 1 t 418 28 61 70
240 36 
60 Henry 1 f 401 26 74 115
255 37 
22 Rick 1 t 420 20 65 88
226 36 
66 Noe 1 t 408 27 61 80
225 36 
52 Eduardo 1 f 365 34 67 100
217 34 
28 Robbie 1 f 382 32 55 96
221 34 
36 Junichi 1 t 401 23 60 88
267 39 
19 Koji 1 t 364 28 47 113
236 35 
67 Brandon 1 t 392 25 66 122
210 37 
10 Ryan 2 t 592 44 82 210
406 95 29 5 
23 Blake 2 t 577 29 99 121
432 80 16 3 
7 Christian 2 t 599 34 117 196
416 95 31 6 
47 Travis 3 t 669 58 78 201
451 136 34 1 
48 Pablo 5 t 628 45 74 139
368 96 1 0 
13 Hanley 3 t 575 37 94 148
388 80 23 0 
15 Dustin 4 t 635 36 105 227
304 113 28 1 
26 Brock 4 t 1443 33 83 422
454 274 50 2 
5 Allen 3 t 654 40 108 125
383 60 2 1 
2 Xander 6 t 602 48 95 137
420 64 14 3 
50 Mookie 8 t 584 35 84 199
323 110 31 7 
25 Jackie 7 t 608 53 92 161
528 69 1 5 
38 Rusney 9 t 626 47 69 194
422 135 31 0 
34 David 3 f 567 63 99 108
399 55 1 6 
-1
Yankees
38 Andrew 1 t 388 22 67 119
213 37 
68 Dellin 1 t 364 34 65 86
265 32 
26 Chris 1 f 397 19 74 118
232 35 
65 Caleb 1 t 424 33 64 88
279 36 
30 Nathan 1 t 381 35 59 85
250 37 
74 Nick 1 t 417 33 80 92
235 33 
33 Chris 1 t 414 25 52 85
238 38 
48 Andrew 1 f 386 28 66 110
242 35 
55 Brian 1 t 419 25 48 76
273 34 
47 Ivan 1 t 445 24 51 108
256 35 
67 James 1 f 427 26 51 120
217 37 
57 Branden 1 t 416 22 73 106
212 37 
35 Michael 1 t 398 28 61 109
283 35 
50 Nick 1 t 426 24 62 95
231 37 
45 Chasen 1 f 399 18 60 74
243 35 
52 CC 1 f 397 23 49 108
234 35 
40 Luis 1 t 405 20 64 131
240 38 
19 Masahiro 1 t 420 31 26 89
195 33 
43 Adam 1 t 416 28 54 98
240 33 
41 Justin 1 f 365 26 49 104
251 35 
34 Brian 2 t 637 41 79 147
365 66 1 1 
66 John 2 t 584 58 81 150
434 92 21 1 
53 Austin 2 t 593 47 98 122
423 62 17 3 
73 Gary 2 t 709 43 66 194
407 152 35 2 
31 Greg 3 t 672 66 78 157
299 60 1 5 
14 Stephen 4 t 607 44 53 158
390 99 16 5 
18 Didi 6 t 613 33 55 217
479 126 29 3 
12 Chase 5 t 553 58 97 146
332 83 2 5 
63 Jose 4 t 683 49 124 124
380 71 12 2 
64 Robert 4 t 662 43 96 144
395 65 6 2 
17 Brendan 4 t 658 55 61 162
382 96 28 2 
29 Dustin 7 t 587 63 82 156
461 119 22 1 
36 Carlos 9 t 545 50 94 129
373 90 4 4 
22 Jacoby 8 f 657 42 43 142
473 51 1 3 
11 Brett 7 f 551 32 120 145
406 131 26 1 
72 Slade 8 f 543 50 97 132
399 70 23 2 
70 Rico 9 t 646 22 83 259
433 175 40 6 
25 Chris 9 t 576 34 103 153
432 74 6 3 
-1
BlueJays
56 Mark 1 f 440 21 63 123
208 33 
27 Brett 1 f 405 31 63 117
218 36 
50 Steve 1 t 438 30 74 106
251 38 
43 RA 1 t 384 32 72 88
254 38 
25 Marco 1 t 438 27 67 104
243 34 
35 Jeff 1 f 409 32 63 100
228 32 
32 LaTroy 1 t 402 21 66 57
261 36 
31 Liam 1 t 380 25 74 100
252 34 
36 Drew 1 t 375 26 78 83
251 36 
64 Chad 1 t 421 27 63 97
253 31 
62 Aaron 1 f 403 33 64 96
277 35 
57 Mark 1 t 376 24 59 113
234 34 
54 Roberto 1 t 423 21 58 121
247 34 
14 David 1 f 432 26 54 119
201 38 
41 Aaron 1 t 410 18 60 107
259 36 
8 AJ 2 t 610 44 115 151
400 54 12 2 
55 Russell 2 t 646 49 79 145
300 79 9 2 
30 Dioner 2 t 686 38 71 111
434 76 21 4 
15 Chris 3 t 606 47 77 126
440 53 11 3 
20 Josh 5 t 605 63 100 150
446 48 8 1 
17 Ryan 4 t 610 21 89 135
420 89 23 2 
9 Cliff 4 t 531 73 94 169
442 47 14 4 
13 Justin 3 f 651 40 85 158
380 82 5 3 
2 Troy 6 t 658 38 87 127
399 57 16 2 
19 Jose 9 t 712 44 115 239
429 145 28 1 
3 Ezequiel 7 f 589 57 104 136
351 75 18 2 
11 Kevin 8 t 671 41 81 158
380 155 31 1 
45 Dalton 8 t 638 36 104 246
343 115 30 2 
7 Ben 7 t 621 37 98 149
382 86 5 4 
-1
Orioles
35 Brad 1 t 392 35 69 116
233 32 
53 Zach 1 f 451 31 45 78
239 34 
16 Wei-yin 1 f 359 25 59 108
237 39 
71 Oliver 1 t 426 21 62 106
241 37 
61 Jason 1 t 385 22 56 103
242 33 
39 Kevin 1 t 383 33 59 104
229 38 
60 Mychal 1 t 397 26 65 118
261 36 
50 Miguel 1 t 411 32 64 83
236 36 
31 Ubaldo 1 t 371 35 69 81
227 35 
52 Steve 1 t 393 32 64 97
257 39 
17 Brian 1 f 425 28 62 113
227 36 
66 T.J. 1 f 386 30 66 91
244 35 
56 Darren 1 t 395 29 75 97
265 35 
65 Chaz 1 t 382 18 46 75
232 34 
57 Jorge 1 t 406 20 58 93
242 33 
30 Chris 1 t 394 38 67 89
226 33 
63 Tyler 1 t 420 27 69 88
278 35 
59 Mike 1 t 358 30 64 124
287 37 
45 Steve 2 t 667 55 130 141
452 57 1 3 
36 Caleb 2 t 545 48 81 165
403 47 10 0 
32 Matt 2 t 625 55 97 119
453 46 0 2 
19 Chris 3 t 636 40 88 95
438 54 0 2 
3 Ryan 4 t 722 35 85 166
436 87 28 2 
2 J.J. 6 t 668 52 99 164
417 136 32 1 
15 Paul 6 t 734 33 99 141
524 78 1 1 
13 Manny 5 t 665 39 63 137
420 45 10 3 
6 Jonathan 4 t 744 44 70 146
402 57 17 4 
34 Christian 3 t 617 40 109 128
447 58 19 3 
12 Dariel 9 t 555 56 99 170
422 111 32 2 
10 Adam 8 t 621 40 95 166
436 119 25 3 
48 Junior 7 t 689 49 123 142
425 107 11 3 
9 David 7 f 605 44 89 146
409 36 10 0 
18 Gerardo 9 f 686 34 80 206
435 116 36 3 
28 Steve 7 t 624 70 72 159
457 108 20 5 
14 Nolan 7 t 682 55 91 140
369 62 6 5 
-1
Rays
35 Matt 1 t 395 23 57 83
208 34 
22 Chris 1 t 371 21 60 84
234 37 
59 Andrew 1 t 420 27 60 105
250 30 
26 Brad 1 t 376 28 66 110
259 37 
31 Xavier 1 f 423 31 59 92
224 37 
37 Alex 1 t 409 21 56 111
272 37 
54 Steven 1 t 412 31 79 90
244 38 
47 Brandon 1 t 407 22 69 102
226 36 
51 Nathan 1 f 409 20 62 88
265 36 
57 Jake 1 f 373 27 78 101
223 36 
55 Matt 1 t 375 32 61 104
247 35 
23 Jake 1 t 392 25 56 82
219 37 
30 Erasmo 1 t 434 34 26 102
270 35 
34 C.J. 1 f 408 25 69 87
235 35 
45 Enny 1 f 391 26 63 106
211 35 
33 Drew 1 f 385 28 75 98
226 39 
49 Kirby 1 t 359 22 59 129
237 39 
40 J.P. 2 t 612 39 114 163
393 99 28 2 
46 Luke 2 t 593 56 124 191
371 201 38 0 
44 Rene 2 t 670 39 94 158
438 62 1 3 
1 Tim 4 t 630 44 98 157
390 155 29 2 
13 Asdrubal 6 t 680 46 100 127
455 43 7 4 
11 Logan 4 t 547 46 107 142
391 100 0 3 
2 Nick 4 t 1065 47 76 214
496 157 32 4 
21 James 3 t 638 56 97 217
397 103 29 1 
3 Evan 5 t 624 61 102 140
442 63 16 3 
36 Richie 3 t 658 36 81 143
419 63 0 2 
5 Brandon 1 t 410 30 66 80
254 39 
39 Kevin 1 t 414 34 63 84
238 35 
27 Mikie 1 t 388 24 65 89
238 33 
7 Daniel 1 t 384 23 61 89
259 35 
24 Grady 1 t 371 29 68 106
224 38 
20 Steven 1 t 406 16 54 103
247 35 
-1
```

Comment: Does your scanner input end with a "-1" token?

Comment: Also, is the `Roster` object that you are updating actually a roster in any `Team` collection in the `League`?

Comment: @cybersam Yeah it does end with a "-1" token after every team. Here I'll post the file that I'm reading off of to give you an example. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by your last question, but I think yes.

Answer (score 0):

Since your input always ends each roster's data with a "-1", your current code is calling `Roster.clear()` -- clearing the `Roster` object right after it had been filled with data. That is one reason why your team rosters are always empty.

Also, you are re-using the same `Roster` object for every team. Every team needs its own roster.

To fix both of these issues, replace the `Roster.clear()` call with:

```
Roster = new HashMap<Integer, Player>();
```

That will ensure you have a new roster map for each roster, and that you never empty out a roster.

Comment: You just pulled so much stress off my shoulders, thank you so much. <3